# Sequelize Postgres query JSONB ARRAY

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Have a table `Profile` with a column named `records` which is `ARRAY` of `JSONB`. The `records` column is in the following shape:

```js
[
  {
    itemId: 1,
    value: true,
    insertOn: '2018-03-26T03:49:55.121Z',
  },
  {
    itemId: 1,
    value: false,
    insertOn: '2018-03-27T03:49:55.121Z',
  },
];
```

What I am looking forwards to find is the latest value of a given `itemId`. For example, the latest value of itemId 1 is `false`.

How can I implement the query? I've tried `sequelize.fn('UNNEST', sequelize.col('records'))` but dont know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to expand a JSON column to a rowset. Then you can use `->>` to access its elements:

```
select  ele->>'value'
from    YourTable
cross join lateral
       jsonb_array_elements(col1) arr(ele)
where  ele->>'itemId' = '1'
order by
       ele->>'insertOn' desc
limit  1
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3ec55/3/0)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But how can I implement it in Sequelize 4?

Comment: I can do it in SQL, but don't know much about Sequelize:)